# RichTextBox Paste running into problems

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, clipboard

I have a legacy application that is using a `RichTextBox` control to manage a document.

I have the source but can't re-compile due to licensing.

The section causing problems is below:

```
RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.ReadOnly = False
i = RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Find(Chr(160))
If i > 0 Then
    RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart = i
    RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionLength = 1
    TmpStr = Pub_Base_Folder & "\Templates\Stamp.gif"
    If IO.File.Exists("filepath.gif") = True Then

        Img = Image.FromFile(TmpStr)
        Clipboard.SetImage(Img)
        RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Paste() ' <-- Issue is here

    End If
    Clipboard.SetText(vbNewLine & Today.ToLongDateString)
    RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Paste() ' <-- Issue is here
    TmpStr = "filename.rtf"
    If IO.File.Exists(TmpStr) = True Then
        IO.File.Move(TmpStr, TmpStr & ".tmp")
        RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SaveFile(TmpStr)
        IO.File.Delete(TmpStr & ".tmp")
    End If
End If
```

The application uses `RichTextBox.Paste()` to enter data into the RichTextBox (this seems crazy to me) but it seems to be either pasting the data out of order, missing one or the other of the items or saving the document before any data is pasted. I presume this is because the `.Paste()` operation isn't synchronous?

Is there any way I can prevent this behaviour without having to re-compile?

If not, can this be fixed just with a `DoEvents()`?

Comment: Can you explain what did you experienced while you did a step-by-step debugging with details?

Comment: @LajosArpad Stepping through in debugging works as intended because the `Paste()` function is always finished by the time the next line runs.

Comment: What if you put a breakpoint to the lines where Paste is being called? If your assumption is correct, then this should reproduce the problem.